# Vuejs How to assign an array to another array in such a way that the two arrays are not reactive to changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I faced with this challenge to assign array to another array such that the arrays won't be reactive on changes from one of the array.

So to achieve this I made a local copy of the same array and assigned one to another but I would love to do stuffs dynamically where I am having the reactive issues.

Below is what am trying to achieve

```
const ComponentA = {
  data: function() {
    return {
      categories:[
        {
          name: 'Category 1',
          series: [
            {
              name: 'Series 1',
              value: 5
            },
            {
              name: 'Series 2',
              value: 5
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'Category 2',
          series: [
            {
              name: 'Series 1',
              value: 50
            },
            {
              name: 'Series 2',
              value: 56
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      tempCategories:[
        {
          name: 'Category 1',
          series: [
            {
              name: 'Series 1',
              value: 5
            },
            {
              name: 'Series 2',
              value: 5
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'Category 2',
          series: [
            {
              name: 'Series 1',
              value: 50
            },
            {
              name: 'Series 2',
              value: 56
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    resetCategory() {
      this.tempCategories.forEach((category,i)=>{
        category.series.forEach((series,j)=>{
          this.categories[i].series[j] = series;
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

after computations on categories i can reset the categories array with tempCategories by calling

```
this.resetCategory() and it works as expected.
```

Meanwhile I want to be able to do this assignment dynamically whereby when i have copy of the category array I can assign the array to both categories and tempCategories arrays, respectively and after computations with categories array i can reset the categories array with tempCategories array. So I did the following.

```
initialize(category) {
  this.tempCategories = category;
  this.categories = category;
}
```

I realize changes in this.categories reflects on this.tempCategories; I've even used the following options

```
initialize(category) {
  this.tempCategories = category.slice(); 
  //or this.tempCategories = Json.parse(Json.stringify(category));

  this.categories = category.slice();
  //or this.categories = Json.parse(Json.stringify(category));
}
```

yet the two arrays are still reactive. Please I need help on how to solve this problem.

Comment: It seems like your `initialize` function and `this.categories[i].series[j] = series;` would still result in the same object existing in both arrays. I typically use `_.cloneDeep` for stuff like this, though there are other methods. Just make sure you are always creating a deep copy. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep

Comment: You could use `Array.map` or `.slice` to create an entirely new array. Try replacing the `forEach` parts with the above.

Comment: Be careful, `map` create new array, but the object inside still reference to old obj, so `newArray[0].something = newThing` will change the `oldArray[0]` as well. I always use cloneDeep to make sure it is separated.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys, it works now both method

```
initialize(categories){
  //let copy = _.cloneDeep(categories);
  let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categories));
  this.tempCategories = copy;
  this.categories = copy;
},

resetCategories(){
  //this.categories = _.cloneDeep(this.tempCategories);
  this.categories = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.tempCategories)); 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such `Json`. but It may be `JSON`.

```
initialize(category) {
  this.tempCategories = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(category));
  this.categories = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(category));
}
```

And you can't prevent fake copy of by

```
  this.tempCategories = category;
  this.categories = category;
```

May be those three `Array`s are exactly same even one of them is updated.